# Routing and Mixing Capability ALSA

Tags: alsa

What is meant by Routing and Mixing capability in ALSA?

For Reference:
Link -  https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/ALSA_overview#Purpose

Comment: Does https://bootlin.com/blog/audio-multi-channel-routing-and-mixing-using-alsalib/ help?